# SQL Server warning for DROP DATABASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The `DROP DATABASE <*dbname*>` command in T-SQL can cause a world of hurt, if executed in the wrong SQL Server session window or with the wrong db name.

Seems like a good situation for the equivalent of the old DOS "Are you sure?" warning.

Is there any setting in SQL Server that can put something like this in effect for a given database?

Comment: No. There are NO prompts in SQL and there better NEVER be any.

Comment: The only *safety setting* is your **brain** - engage it before starting to drop databases!

Comment: Really, if they need a warning then don't give them the authority.  What about alter, truncate, delete, update, ...?  Where does it stop?   Not having a backup can also cause a world of hurt.

Comment: @Steve: I don't think he is asking for a prompt "in SQL" or "in SQL Server", but a prompt in the SQL client (SSMS most probably)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes.  that's the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a DDL Trigger , something like....

```
ALTER TRIGGER DB_Drop_Warnning 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR DROP_DATABASE
AS 
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(100),
        @eventData XML

SET @eventData = EVENTDATA()            
SELECT @DatabaseName = @eventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]','varchar(128)')

IF @DatabaseName IN ('TEST_DB1','TEST_DB2','TEST_DB3')  --<-- your database name(s) here 
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Disable the trigger before you can drop the database.' 
    ROLLBACK;
  END
GO
```

**Enable the trigger:**

```
 ENABLE TRIGGER [DB_Drop_Warnning] ON ALL SERVER 
 GO
```

Now if you try to drop that database it will throw the following error:

```
Disable the trigger before you can drop the database. 
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

When you want to drop the database just disable the trigger:

```
 DISABLE TRIGGER [DB_Drop_Warnning] ON ALL SERVER 
 GO
```